# Editing an armature while in edit mode?

Tags: armature

My problem is the armature returns to the rest pose when in edit mode.

Is it possible to edit an armature after giving it a pose?

I do not mean the mesh because I know I can enable/disable armature modifiers in edit mode. I only mention this because this is the answers I get whenever I try Googling an answer for my question.

Comment: the rest pose and the edit positions are the same, if you want to make a particular pose the rest pose (and therefore the edit positions) you need to switch to pose mode and header menu > Pose > Apply > Apply Pose as Rest Pose, but it will change both the rest pose and the edit position of the bones